# Conditionally slice last 3 characters in DataFrame based on if a dash is present

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a DataFrame that has around 10,000 values like this:

```
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+
| 12-4253    |
+------------+
| 24-3521-01 |
+------------+
| 46-745     |
+------------+
| 13-2131-02 |
+------------+
```

I want to be able to check to see if two dashes exist in a cell, and then remove the second dash and the values, and end up with this:

```
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
| 12-4253   |
+-----------+
| 24-3521   |
+-----------+
| 46-745    |
+-----------+
| 13-2131   |
+-----------+
```

Since checking for substrings wouldn't really work in checking for multiples of a substring, I thought I would do the following:

```
i = 0
for item in DF:
    item = str(item) # Had to put this because of an issue where floats can't be sub-stringed?
    lastThree = item[-3:]

    if "-" in lastThree:
        correctItem = item[:-3]
        DF.set_value(i, 'id', correctItem)
    i+=1
```

But that doesn't seem to work...

Can anyone direct me to a more elegant and civilized solution to this problem? Is substringing the last 3 values turning it into a float, and that's why it can't find the hyphen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.Series.split`

```
df['id'].str.split('-', 2).str[:2].str.join('-').to_frame()

        id
0  12-4253
1  24-3521
2   46-745
3  13-2131
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = df['id'].str.extract('^([\d+]+-[\d+]+)', expand=False)
print (df)
0    12-4253
1    24-3521
2     46-745
3    13-2131
Name: id, dtype: object
```